# How to write program counter in SystemVerilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, synthesis

I was trying to build an 8-bit program counter, and it should support branching. This is what I wrote:

```
module programme_counter (clock,sel,immediate,pc);
input [7:0] immediate;
input clock,sel;
output [7:0] pc;
begin
    always @ (posedge clock)
    if (pc<3'd256)
        if (sel)
            pc <= pc + 1;
        else
            assign pc = immediate;
    else
        pc <= 0;
end
endmodule
```

The functionality of this code should be:

```
at every rising edge of the clock signal:
      if pc value < 256
           if sel == 1
               pc at the next rising edge should be the pc before the next edge + 1
           if sel ==0
               pc at the next rising edge should be immediate value
      if pc value >= 256
           pc at the next rising edge should be 0
```

Can anyone help me to check if the code describes the function correctly?

Comment: Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you declared the `pc` signal as 8 bits wide.  This means `pc` can be any value from 0 to 255.  It can not be 256 or greater.  So, the expression `if pc value < 256` it always true, and the expression `if pc value >= 256` is never true.

Keep in mind that an 8-bit counter will automatically roll over.  If `pc` is 255, on the next `posedge` of `clock`, it will increment and roll over to 0.

With that in mind, here is a version of your code that compiles without errors:

```
module programme_counter (clock,sel,immediate,pc);
    input [7:0] immediate;
    input clock,sel;
    output reg [7:0] pc;
    always @ (posedge clock)
        if (sel)
            pc <= pc + 1;
        else
            pc <= immediate;
endmodule
```

You must decide if it meets your requirements.  The way to check if your Verilog code behaves the way you expect is to write a testbench, also using Verilog code.  Refer to [Can anyone help me to create a Verilog testbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073029/can-anyone-help-me-to-create-a-verilog-testbench)

Here are some syntax notes:

- You should not use the `assign` keyword inside an `always` block
- You should use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) everywhere in your sequential logic `always` block
- There's no need for the `begin/end` keywords outside the `always` block
- You should declare `pc` as a `reg` since you make procedural assignments to it (inside the `always` block)